# VBA EXCEL: Loop overwriting results

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm having trouble with the code below, that does exactly what I want it to, but it keeps overwriting the results.

It searches for the text "debitor" and if it's true, it copies.

When it finds multiple results which it often does, it overwrites the results.

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ark1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Do
For x = 13 To 20
        If autECLSession.autECLPS.GetTextRect(x, 26, x, 32) = "Debitor" Then
            Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).Value = Trim(autECLSession.autECLPS.GetTextRect(x, 9, x, 17))
        End If
    Next
    autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf8]"
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
Loop Until autECLSession.autECLPS.GetTextRect(22, 2, 22, 36) = "EO0D0018A Der kan ikke bladres frem"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't update  `LastRow`, so you end up writing into the same cell again and again.
Insert an increment like this:

```
    If autECLSession.autECLPS.GetTextRect(x, 26, x, 32) = "Debitor" Then
        Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).Value = Trim(autECLSession.autECLPS.GetTextRect(x, 9, x, 17))
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
```